# Suppress "Unresolved Inclusion" Warning In Eclipse/CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have found plenty of answers on how to fix "include" errors/warnings by listing header directories in `Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes`. However, I am trying to find out if it is possible to suppress a warning for an included header that intentionally does not exist.

The file in this instance is named `config.h` and it is generated from another file named `config.h.in` after invoking the `cmake` build tool. So there is no problem compiling the code. I just get the highlighted warning "Unresolved inclusion" in eclipse. I am looking to suppress this warning but don't know if it is possible.

[image: unresolved-inclusion.png]

I have tried the following but does not work:

```
#include "config.h" // @suppress("Unresolved inclusion")
```

Obviously not a severe problem, but would be nice to be able to suppress it.

Comment: Why not just point Eclipse to where the generated file lives?

Comment: That would only work if the file has been generated.

Comment: Right, that's what I mean: run `cmake`, point Eclipse to the right directory, and all is well.

Comment: That is definitely an option.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, is that the contents of `config.h` might include macro definitions that Eclipse should know about to accurately parse the rest of your code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to suppress individual "Unresolved inclusion" annotations, but I can explain why `@suppress` doesn't work for them.

There are two sources of error/warning annotations in Eclipse CDT:

1. Ones that come from the Code Analysis (CodAn) module. This includes semantic errors, and warnings. (You can see a list of these in `Preferences | C/C++ | Code Analysis`.)
2. Ones that come directly from the indexer. This includes syntax errors, and preprocessor errors (including unresolved inclusion errors).

`@suppress` is a CodAn feature, and as such, it only applies to CodAn annotations.

I'm not aware of a similar feature for the second kind of annotation, beyond hiding this entire category in `Preferences | General | Editors | Text Editors | Annotations | C/C++ Indexer Markers`.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate this clarification.